# I2C communication between RP2040 and adxl357 accelerometer ( C/C++ SDK )

Tags: c++, c, embedded, i2c, raspberry-pi-pico

I need to communicate via I2C to the [adxl357](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl356-357.pdf) accelerometer and a few questions have arisen.
Looking at the [RP2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf) sdk documentation I see that there is a special method to send data to a certain address, such as [i2c_write_blocking()](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__i2c.html#ga5149e9af84926fa19db6677691ab2900). Its arguments include a 7-bit address and the data to be sent. My question is, since the accelerometer needs a Read/Write bit, is it still possible to use this function? Or should I go to the alternative [i2c_write_raw_blocking()](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__i2c.html#gaf33250d48e1ad099b1ade910fa97e38d)?

Also, I don't understand the notation of the Read / Write bit, it is reported with R/#W, would that mean that 1 is Read while 0 is write?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2C addresses have 7 bits: these are sent in the high 7 bits of an 8-bit byte, and remaining bit (the least significant bit) is set to 1 for read, 0 for write.

The reason the documentation says it wants a 7-bit address is because it is telling you that the write function will left-shift the address by one and add a 1, and the read function function will left-shift the address by one and add a 0.

If it didn't tell you this you might pre-shift the address yourself, which would be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand now. I had gotten slightly confused with the concept of writing and reading.